# Monitoring how many request by key

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I Possible trace how many requests an API key made on my gateway URL?
Because I need to create a report of the API usage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using google clouds endpoints, in that case it is easier just to go with the google products:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics

Google cloud already provides all the metrics that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @Kram's response, if you need to monitor API usage per client (or not only per API key) you will need to create specific one GCP project per API client [to able to track it](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).